Unity will be sponsoring Game Development
UPDATE: October 29, 2024
The sponsorship will run through December 31, 2024.

We're pleased to announce that Unity will be sponsoring Game Development starting the week of August 26, running through late November. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what that means.
How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?
The sponsorship will be found on the right side of the header at the top of the site, similar to what you see below.

What else changes?
Not a thing! Borrowing from the original MSE announcement on sponsorships:

First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who could be interested in their products know about them in a non-intrusive way.
What if I've found a design glitch/bug?
If something looks off, please report it as a bug so we can investigate and squash it.
That's all. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.
Lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Game Development Stack Exchange successful.

Could I ask for a preview of how this will look on mobile? (Hoping we have a strategy to avoid this bug this time around)

@DMGregory As you may have seen (since the sponsorship has launched), the logo placement is the same as for the previous one shown in the linked bug post, centered below the site logo.
